# memory leak with resolved Promises retained only by global handles

Tags: node.js

[inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/golSZ.png)

Why would there be Promises that are retained only by "global handles", that are already resolved or rejected, and never garbage collected?

I have a memory leak on a node.js application. Using chrome inspector, I can see that there are Promises that are already resolved. Their status is "resolved", with the result being an IncomingMessage. They obviously relate to an http request that has completed successfully.
I can see in the retainers view, that they are retained only by "Global handles".
The calls are wrapped with async-await, and try-catch.

Comment: `GC` cannot do magic when there are still references to objects. You should trace back those global handlers.

Comment: 'global handles', not 'global handlers'. Trace back how? As I understand 'global handles' is something that comes from async hooks. This is not something that exists anywhere in my code.
Why is this promise different than any other, that is gets held indefinitely by this 'global handles' object, and not held by any other object.

Answer (score 0):

We found and fixed the leak. It was caused by streams received from axios, and piped to a client, that were destroyed and released without being drained. The solution was to call stream.resume() instead of destroy().